# Hide/Show UITextField On Button Press

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitextfield

Simply enough, I need to know how to make a UITextField, in this case, a search bar, hide/show itself when a button is pressed. If possible, some kind of animating to make it smoother would be nice, but all I need is a way to hide this UITextField when I press a button.

EDIT: I wish I could split the checkmark, but thanks for all the help.

I went in using the txt.hidden boolean and used an if-then-if statement to fix it. If anyone needs what I ended up having, here it is:

```
-(IBAction)hideBtn:(id)sender {

  if (googleBar.hidden) {

    googleBar.hidden = NO;

  } else if (!googleBar.hidden) {

    googleBar.hidden = YES;

  }

}
```

EDIT2: This much simpler code also works! Thanks for letting me know!

```
googleBar.hidden = !googleBar.hidden;
```

Comment: `googleBar.hidden = !googleBar.hidden;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use

```
UITextField.hidden = BOOLvalue;
```

Comment: More generally, this works for any subclass of `UIView` since they all inherit the `hidden` property.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Is there any way that I would be able to then set the button to show it again if it is hidden when pressed, and then hide it if it is not hidden, etc.? Perhaps an if-else statement?

Comment: in the fact your hideBtn method can have only one line googleBar.hidden = !googleBar.hidden; :)

Answer (score 1):

```
-(void) btnPressed:(id) sender {
txt.hidden = YES;
}
```

txt refer to a TextField..   Just set the hidden property to YES ...

To be smoother, you may add a timer to set alpha of textfield reduce progressively

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now, how may I have it so that if it is hidden, the button instead shows it again when pressed?

Answer (score 0):

The `UITextField` ultimately inherits from UIView.  All `UIView` objects have the inherent ability to hide using the `hidden` property.  [See this link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIView) for more details on `UIView`, particularly the `hidden` property.

Here's a ***rough*** example of what your code might look like:

```
..
..
UIButton *myBtn = ....
[myBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(myBtnTap:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

- (void)myBtnTap:(id)sender
{
   myTextField.hidden = YES; //or no depending on some logic
}
```